# Running a Python program from java, with arguments

Tags: java, python, runtime

working on a presentation for school, I coded the java part, someone else did the python which i dont know.

I have a java application that uses JavaFX to open a window asking for information, which is then supposed to take information and feed it to a python program to use.

basic idea is that the program would take a phone number, provider, and what kind of message they want, and send it to them.

I dont know how to run a python program through java, nor how to pass data when doing it.

Java :

```
package showcase.program;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
//import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;

public class ShowcaseProgram extends Application {

   String PhoneNum;
   String CarrierNumStr;
   String ChoiceStr;
   final Button button = new Button ("Submit");
   final Label notification = new Label ();
   final Label notification2 = new Label ();
    @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) {

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 500, 500);
    final ComboBox CarriersCombo = new ComboBox();
        CarriersCombo.getItems().addAll(
            "Verison",
            "Sprint",
            "T-Mobile",
            "AT&T",
            "MetroPCS",
            "Boost Mobile",
            "Cricket Wireless",
            "Staight Talk",
            "Virgin Mobile"

        );
    final ComboBox ChoiceCombo = new ComboBox();
        ChoiceCombo.getItems().addAll(
            "Insult",
            "Compliment"
        );
     TextField PhoneNumIn = new TextField ();  
    PhoneNumIn.setText("Label");
    PhoneNumIn.clear();


         button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                int count = 0;
                if (ChoiceCombo.getValue() == null){
                notification.setText("You have not selected : insult or compliment"); 
                count++;
                }
                if (CarriersCombo.getValue() == null){
                notification.setText("You have not selected a Carrier!"); 
                count++;
                }
                if (PhoneNumIn.getText() ==  null){
                notification.setText("You have not entered a Phone number");
                count++;
                }
                if(PhoneNumIn.getText() == null){ //try to get google api imported properly for this to use Ints.tryParse()
                notification.setText("Please make sure your phone number is numeric only.");
                count++;
                }
                System.out.println(count);



                if (count == 0){
                    PhoneNum = PhoneNumIn.getText();
                    CarrierNumStr = CarriersCombo.getValue().toString();
                    ChoiceStr = ChoiceCombo.getValue().toString();
                    PhoneNumIn.setText(null);
                    CarriersCombo.setValue(null);
                    ChoiceCombo.setValue(null);
                    notification.setText("Thank you");
                } else {
                    notification2.setText("The information you inputed is incorrect, please try again.");
                }
           }     
         });







    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setVgap(4);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    grid.add(new Label("Phone Number :"), 0, 0);
    grid.add(PhoneNumIn, 1, 0);
    grid.add(new Label("Carrier :"),0 , 2);
    grid.add(CarriersCombo, 1 , 2);
    grid.add(new Label("Choice :"), 0, 3);
    grid.add(ChoiceCombo, 1 , 3);
    grid.add(button, 1, 4);
    grid.add(notification, 1, 5);
    grid.add(notification2, 1, 6);
    Group root = (Group) scene.getRoot();
    root.getChildren().add(grid);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    }

    public static void launchPy(String PhoneNum, int Carrier, String Msg){

    }


    public static int CarrierToInt(String Carr){
        int x;
            if (Carr == "Verison"){
                x = 7;
            } else if (Carr == "Sprint"){
                x = 5;
            } else if(Carr == "T-Mobile") {
                x = 6;
            } else if(Carr == "AT&T") {
                x = 0;
            } else if(Carr == "MetroPCS") {
                x = 3;
            } else if(Carr == "Boost Mobile") {
                x = 1;
            } else if(Carr == "Cricket Wireless") {
                x = 2;
            } else if(Carr == "Straight Talk") {
                x = 4;
            } else if(Carr == "Virgin Mobile") {
                x = 8;
            }

            else {
                x = 0;
            }
        return x;
    }

    public static String Message(String ChoiceStr){
        int RNG;
        RNG = (int )(Math.random() * 1 + 3);
        String msg = "";
        String[] insults = new String[5];
        String[] compliments = new String[5];
        insults[1] = "Fart You";//preset insults and compliments go here
        insults[2] = "";
        insults[3] = "you stink!";
        compliments[1] = "Nice Hair";
        if (ChoiceStr == "Insult"){
            msg = insults[RNG];
        } else {
            msg = compliments[RNG];
        }
    return msg;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       while(true) {
           launch(args);

       }

    }

}
```

The python program is set up to take 3 inputs, as provided in the launchPy method.

ideally, it would be something like (pseudo)

```
public static void launchPy(String PhoneNum, int Carrier, String Msg){
string pythonLocation = "/home/...";
//run python(pythonLocation, PhoneNum, Carrier, Msg)
}
```

but i dont know how to do that part.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please try posting your code again with proper indentation.  Paste the code into the window, select it, and click the `{}` icon.  Every line will be shifted 4 spaces to the right.  Avoid tabs when pasting, or use 4 spaces per tab.

Comment: Alright just fixed it.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Now please try to make it a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by removing all the stuff that isn't essential.  This helps focus our attention on the issue, and often helps you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python",pythonLocation,""+PhoneNum,""+
       Carrier,""+Msg);
    Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: whats the format for the pythonLocation, would it just be :
"C:\pythonprogram\text_automation"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Process process;   
String commands = "python ... "
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command(commands);
process = pb.start();
```